# jsconfig.js file not working with symlink package

Tags: node.js, reactjs, visual-studio-code, nestjs-config, vscode-jsconfig

I have a React node repo that imports from a custom node repo. Both repos are located in my local machine. I have `jsconfig.js` files in both repo, using VS code. However, only the React repo is recognizing the `jsconfig.js` file. The `jsconfig.js` file in the imported module appears to be completely ignored.

The the imported module is symlinked into my React repo via npm like so:

`npm link`

This is what is in both `jsconfig.js` files:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "baseUrl": "./src"
  }
}
```

Why is the `jsconfig.js` file being completely ignored in the imported module. Does being symlinked causes this?